# GMap.Net сдвинуть нулевой меридиан

Tags: c#, map, gmap.net

Всем привет. Как в GMap.Net сдвинуть нулевой меридиан, т.е. необходимо, чтобы карта отображалась сдвинутой вбок ???

Уточняю поставленный вопрос. Мне нужно, чтобы по умолчанию нулевой меридиан был в крайнем левом положении.
Вот так сейчас
[image]
Нужно чтобы было так
[image]

Сейчас код выглядит так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using GMap.NET;
using GMap.NET.MapProviders;
using GMap.NET.WindowsForms;
using GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers;
using GMap.NET.WindowsForms.ToolTips;
using System.Reflection;


namespace Map
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();                       
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Инициализация карты
        GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.CacheOnly;
        // Импорт Кэша
        GMaps.Instance.ImportFromGMDB("DataExp.gmdb");

        gmap.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GoogleMapProvider.Instance;          
        gmap.SetPositionByKeywords("Maputo, Mozambique");

        // Добавить маркер на карту 
        GMapOverlay markersOverlay = new GMapOverlay("markers");
        GMarkerGoogle marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(-25.966688,         32.580528),
        GMarkerGoogleType.green);
        markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
        gmap.Overlays.Add(markersOverlay);


        /* Добавить полигон на карту
        GMapOverlay polyOverlay = new GMapOverlay("polygons");
        List<PointLatLng> points = new List<PointLatLng>();
        points.Add(new PointLatLng(-25.969562, 32.585789));
        points.Add(new PointLatLng(-25.966205, 32.588171));
        points.Add(new PointLatLng(-25.968134, 32.591647));
        points.Add(new PointLatLng(-25.971684, 32.589759));
        GMapPolygon polygon = new GMapPolygon(points, "mypolygon");
        polygon.Fill = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Red));
        polygon.Stroke = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
        polyOverlay.Polygons.Add(polygon);
        gmap.Overlays.Add(polyOverlay);
        */                       
    }

    private void gmap_OnMarkerClick(GMapMarker marker, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Marker {0} was clicked.", marker.Tag));
        //marker.ToolTipMode = MarkerTooltipMode.OnMouseOver;
        marker.ToolTipText = marker.Position.ToString();


    }

    private void gmap_OnMarkerLeave(GMapMarker marker)
    {
        marker.ToolTipText = "";
    }


}
}
```

Не понятно, какой метод использовать для решения задачи.

Comment: Более конкретно сформулируйте вопрос. Что хочется получить в ответе? "Как сдвинуть" - это слишком абстрактная формулировка. Также в идеале, привести некую часть кода, в которой что-либо не получается.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Уточнил свой вопрос. Обновите страницу пожалуйста.

Comment: Привёл код. Рассчитываю на вашу помощь.